# OpenCV Android camera upside down ISSUE

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-camera

i am working on face detection app in android.
i have used open cv 3.4.14 library and using front camera. the camera index is set to 1. but the streaming is upside down. i tried almost all of the solutions from stack overflow but nothing is working.

in open cv's JavaCameraView class, i also added mCamera.startPreviewDisplay(getHolder()) that fixed the orientation but i immedietely went into NULL POINTER EXCEPTION "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Canvas.getHeight()' on a null object reference"

Note that i am working on Samsung galaxy S21 and OS is Android 12.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved the problem myself by changing CameraViewBridgeBase.java code by following

```
package org.opencv.android;

import java.util.List;
import org.opencv.R;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

/**
 * This is a basic class, implementing the interaction with Camera and 
OpenCV library.
 * The main responsibility of it - is to control when camera can be 
 enabled, process the frame,
 * call external listener to make any adjustments to the frame and then 
draw the resulting
 * frame to the screen.
 * The clients shall implement CvCameraViewListener.
 */
public abstract class CameraBridgeViewBase extends SurfaceView implements 
SurfaceHolder.Callback {

   private static final String TAG = "CameraBridge";
   private static final int MAX_UNSPECIFIED = -1;
   private static final int STOPPED = 0;
   private static final int STARTED = 1;
   private int mState = STOPPED;
   private Bitmap mCacheBitmap;
   private CvCameraViewListener2 mListener;
   private boolean mSurfaceExist;
   private Object mSyncObject = new Object();

   protected int mFrameWidth;
   protected int mFrameHeight;
   protected int mMaxHeight;
   protected int mMaxWidth;
   protected float mScale = 0;
   protected int mPreviewFormat = RGBA;
   protected int mCameraIndex = CAMERA_ID_ANY;
   protected boolean mEnabled;
   protected FpsMeter mFpsMeter = null;
   private final Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();

   public static final int CAMERA_ID_ANY   = -1;
   public static final int CAMERA_ID_BACK  = 99;
   public static final int CAMERA_ID_FRONT = 98;
   public static final int RGBA = 1;
   public static final int GRAY = 2;

   public CameraBridgeViewBase(Context context, int cameraId) {
       super(context);
       mCameraIndex = cameraId;
       getHolder().addCallback(this);
       mMaxWidth = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
       mMaxHeight = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
    }

public CameraBridgeViewBase(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    int count = attrs.getAttributeCount();
    Log.d(TAG, "Attr count: " + Integer.valueOf(count));

    TypedArray styledAttrs = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, 
R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase);
    if (styledAttrs.getBoolean(R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase_show_fps, 
false))
        enableFpsMeter();

        mCameraIndex = 
styledAttrs.getInt(R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase_camera_id, -1);

        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mMaxWidth = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
        mMaxHeight = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
       styledAttrs.recycle();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the camera index
    * @param cameraIndex new camera index
    */
    public void setCameraIndex(int cameraIndex) {
        this.mCameraIndex = cameraIndex;
    }

    public interface CvCameraViewListener {
        /**
        * This method is invoked when camera preview has started. After this method is invoked
         * the frames will start to be delivered to client via the onCameraFrame() callback.
         * @param width -  the width of the frames that will be delivered
         * @param height - the height of the frames that will be delivered
         */
        public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height);

        /**
         * This method is invoked when camera preview has been stopped for some reason.
         * No frames will be delivered via onCameraFrame() callback after this method is called.
         */
        public void onCameraViewStopped();

        /**
         * This method is invoked when delivery of the frame needs to be done.
         * The returned values - is a modified frame which needs to be displayed on the screen.
         * TODO: pass the parameters specifying the format of the frame (BPP, YUV or RGB and etc)
         */
        public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame);
    }

    public interface CvCameraViewListener2 {
        /**
         * This method is invoked when camera preview has started. After this method is invoked
         * the frames will start to be delivered to client via the onCameraFrame() callback.
         * @param width -  the width of the frames that will be delivered
         * @param height - the height of the frames that will be delivered
         */
        public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height);

        /**
         * This method is invoked when camera preview has been stopped for some reason.
         * No frames will be delivered via onCameraFrame() callback after this method is called.
         */
        public void onCameraViewStopped();

        /**
         * This method is invoked when delivery of the frame needs to be done.
         * The returned values - is a modified frame which needs to be displayed on the screen.
     * TODO: pass the parameters specifying the format of the frame (BPP, YUV or RGB and etc)
     */
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame);
};

protected class CvCameraViewListenerAdapter implements CvCameraViewListener2  {
    public CvCameraViewListenerAdapter(CvCameraViewListener oldStypeListener) {
        mOldStyleListener = oldStypeListener;
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mOldStyleListener.onCameraViewStarted(width, height);
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mOldStyleListener.onCameraViewStopped();
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Mat result = null;
        switch (mPreviewFormat) {
            case RGBA:
                result = mOldStyleListener.onCameraFrame(inputFrame.rgba());
                break;
            case GRAY:
                result = mOldStyleListener.onCameraFrame(inputFrame.gray());
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Invalid frame format! Only RGBA and Gray Scale are supported!");
        };

        return result;
    }

    public void setFrameFormat(int format) {
        mPreviewFormat = format;
    }

    private int mPreviewFormat = RGBA;
    private CvCameraViewListener mOldStyleListener;
};

/**
 * This class interface is abstract representation of single frame from camera for onCameraFrame callback
 * Attention: Do not use objects, that represents this interface out of onCameraFrame callback!
 */
public interface CvCameraViewFrame {

    /**
     * This method returns RGBA Mat with frame
     */
    public Mat rgba();

    /**
     * This method returns single channel gray scale Mat with frame
     */
    public Mat gray();
};

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    Log.d(TAG, "call surfaceChanged event");
    synchronized(mSyncObject) {
        if (!mSurfaceExist) {
            mSurfaceExist = true;
            checkCurrentState();
        } else {
            /** Surface changed. We need to stop camera and restart with new parameters */
            /* Pretend that old surface has been destroyed */
            mSurfaceExist = false;
            checkCurrentState();
            /* Now use new surface. Say we have it now */
            mSurfaceExist = true;
            checkCurrentState();
        }
    }
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    /* Do nothing. Wait until surfaceChanged delivered */
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    synchronized(mSyncObject) {
        mSurfaceExist = false;
        checkCurrentState();
    }
}

/**
 * This method is provided for clients, so they can enable the camera connection.
 * The actual onCameraViewStarted callback will be delivered only after both this method is called and surface is available
 */
public void enableView() {
    synchronized(mSyncObject) {
        mEnabled = true;
        checkCurrentState();
    }
}

/**
 * This method is provided for clients, so they can disable camera connection and stop
 * the delivery of frames even though the surface view itself is not destroyed and still stays on the scren
 */
public void disableView() {
    synchronized(mSyncObject) {
        mEnabled = false;
        checkCurrentState();
    }
}

/**
 * This method enables label with fps value on the screen
 */
public void enableFpsMeter() {
    if (mFpsMeter == null) {
        mFpsMeter = new FpsMeter();
        mFpsMeter.setResolution(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
    }
}

public void disableFpsMeter() {
    mFpsMeter = null;
}

/**
 *
 * @param listener
 */

public void setCvCameraViewListener(CvCameraViewListener2 listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public void setCvCameraViewListener(CvCameraViewListener listener) {
    CvCameraViewListenerAdapter adapter = new CvCameraViewListenerAdapter(listener);
    adapter.setFrameFormat(mPreviewFormat);
    mListener = adapter;
}

/**
 * This method sets the maximum size that camera frame is allowed to be. When selecting
 * size - the biggest size which less or equal the size set will be selected.
 * As an example - we set setMaxFrameSize(200,200) and we have 176x152 and 320x240 sizes. The
 * preview frame will be selected with 176x152 size.
 * This method is useful when need to restrict the size of preview frame for some reason (for example for video recording)
 * @param maxWidth - the maximum width allowed for camera frame.
 * @param maxHeight - the maximum height allowed for camera frame
 */
public void setMaxFrameSize(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    mMaxWidth = maxWidth;
    mMaxHeight = maxHeight;
}

public void SetCaptureFormat(int format)
{
    mPreviewFormat = format;
    if (mListener instanceof CvCameraViewListenerAdapter) {
        CvCameraViewListenerAdapter adapter = (CvCameraViewListenerAdapter) mListener;
        adapter.setFrameFormat(mPreviewFormat);
    }
}

/**
 * Called when mSyncObject lock is held
 */
private void checkCurrentState() {
    Log.d(TAG, "call checkCurrentState");
    int targetState;

    if (mEnabled && mSurfaceExist && getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
        targetState = STARTED;
    } else {
        targetState = STOPPED;
    }

    if (targetState != mState) {
        /* The state change detected. Need to exit the current state and enter target state */
        processExitState(mState);
        mState = targetState;
        processEnterState(mState);
    }
}

private void processEnterState(int state) {
    Log.d(TAG, "call processEnterState: " + state);
    switch(state) {
        case STARTED:
            onEnterStartedState();
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onCameraViewStarted(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
            }
            break;
        case STOPPED:
            onEnterStoppedState();
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onCameraViewStopped();
            }
            break;
    };
}

private void processExitState(int state) {
    Log.d(TAG, "call processExitState: " + state);
    switch(state) {
        case STARTED:
            onExitStartedState();
            break;
        case STOPPED:
            onExitStoppedState();
            break;
    };
}

private void onEnterStoppedState() {
    /* nothing to do */
}

private void onExitStoppedState() {
    /* nothing to do */
}

// NOTE: The order of bitmap constructor and camera connection is important for android 4.1.x
// Bitmap must be constructed before surface
private void onEnterStartedState() {
    Log.d(TAG, "call onEnterStartedState");
    /* Connect camera */
    if (!connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight())) {
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
        ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button
        ad.setMessage("It seems that you device does not support camera (or it is locked). Application will be closed.");
        ad.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,  "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
            }
        });
        ad.show();

    }
}

private void onExitStartedState() {
    disconnectCamera();
    if (mCacheBitmap != null) {
        mCacheBitmap.recycle();
    }
}

/**
 * This method shall be called by the subclasses when they have valid
 * object and want it to be delivered to external client (via callback) and
 * then displayed on the screen.
 * @param frame - the current frame to be delivered
 */
protected void deliverAndDrawFrame(CvCameraViewFrame frame) {
    Mat modified;

    if (mListener != null) {
        modified = mListener.onCameraFrame(frame);
    } else {
        modified = frame.rgba();
    }

    boolean bmpValid = true;
    if (modified != null) {
        try {
            Utils.matToBitmap(modified, mCacheBitmap);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Mat type: " + modified);
            Log.e(TAG, "Bitmap type: " + mCacheBitmap.getWidth() + "*" + mCacheBitmap.getHeight());
            Log.e(TAG, "Utils.matToBitmap() throws an exception: " + e.getMessage());
            bmpValid = false;
        }
    }

    if (bmpValid && mCacheBitmap != null) {
        Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
        if (canvas != null) {
            int saveCount = canvas.save();
            canvas.setMatrix(mMatrix);

            mScale = Math.max((float) canvas.getHeight() / mCacheBitmap.getWidth(), (float) canvas.getWidth() / mCacheBitmap.getHeight());


            canvas.drawColor(0, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            Log.d(TAG, "mStretch value: " + mScale);

            if (mScale != 0) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mCacheBitmap, new Rect(0,0,mCacheBitmap.getWidth(), mCacheBitmap.getHeight()),
                        new Rect((int)((canvas.getWidth() - mScale*mCacheBitmap.getWidth()) / 2),
                                (int)((canvas.getHeight() - mScale*mCacheBitmap.getHeight()) / 2),
                                (int)((canvas.getWidth() - mScale*mCacheBitmap.getWidth()) / 2 + mScale*mCacheBitmap.getWidth()),
                                (int)((canvas.getHeight() - mScale*mCacheBitmap.getHeight()) / 2 + mScale*mCacheBitmap.getHeight())), null);
            } else {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mCacheBitmap, new Rect(0,0,mCacheBitmap.getWidth(), mCacheBitmap.getHeight()),
                        new Rect((canvas.getWidth() - mCacheBitmap.getWidth()) / 2,
                                (canvas.getHeight() - mCacheBitmap.getHeight()) / 2,
                                (canvas.getWidth() - mCacheBitmap.getWidth()) / 2 + mCacheBitmap.getWidth(),
                                (canvas.getHeight() - mCacheBitmap.getHeight()) / 2 + mCacheBitmap.getHeight()), null);
            }
            canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);

            if (mFpsMeter != null) {
                mFpsMeter.measure();
                mFpsMeter.draw(canvas, 20, 30);
            }
            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This method is invoked shall perform concrete operation to initialize the camera.
 * CONTRACT: as a result of this method variables mFrameWidth and mFrameHeight MUST be
 * initialized with the size of the Camera frames that will be delivered to external processor.
 * @param width - the width of this SurfaceView
 * @param height - the height of this SurfaceView
 */
protected abstract boolean connectCamera(int width, int height);

/**
 * Disconnects and release the particular camera object being connected to this surface view.
 * Called when syncObject lock is held
 */
protected abstract void disconnectCamera();

// NOTE: On Android 4.1.x the function must be called before SurfaceTexture constructor!
protected void AllocateCache()
{
    mCacheBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}

public interface ListItemAccessor {
    public int getWidth(Object obj);
    public int getHeight(Object obj);
};

/**
 * This helper method can be called by subclasses to select camera preview size.
 * It goes over the list of the supported preview sizes and selects the maximum one which
 * fits both values set via setMaxFrameSize() and surface frame allocated for this view
 * @param supportedSizes
 * @param surfaceWidth
 * @param surfaceHeight
 * @return optimal frame size
 */
protected Size calculateCameraFrameSize(List<?> supportedSizes, ListItemAccessor accessor, int surfaceWidth, int surfaceHeight) {
    int calcWidth = 0;
    int calcHeight = 0;

    int maxAllowedWidth = (mMaxWidth != MAX_UNSPECIFIED && mMaxWidth < surfaceWidth)? mMaxWidth : surfaceWidth;
    int maxAllowedHeight = (mMaxHeight != MAX_UNSPECIFIED && mMaxHeight < surfaceHeight)? mMaxHeight : surfaceHeight;

    for (Object size : supportedSizes) {
        int width = accessor.getWidth(size);
        int height = accessor.getHeight(size);

        if (width <= maxAllowedWidth && height <= maxAllowedHeight) {
            if (width >= calcWidth && height >= calcHeight) {
                calcWidth = (int) width;
                calcHeight = (int) height;
            }
        }
    }

    return new Size(calcWidth, calcHeight);
}

@Override
public void layout(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.layout(l, t, r, b);
    updateMatrix();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    updateMatrix();
}

private void updateMatrix() {
    float hw = this.getWidth() / 2.0f;
    float hh = this.getHeight() / 2.0f;
    boolean isFrontCamera = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT == mCameraIndex;
    mMatrix.reset();
    if (isFrontCamera) {
        mMatrix.preScale(-1, 1, hw, hh);
    }
    mMatrix.preTranslate(hw, hh);
    if (isFrontCamera)
        mMatrix.preRotate(270);
    else
        mMatrix.preRotate(90);
    mMatrix.preTranslate(-hw, -hh);
    }
}
```